# Adding a.class file into library jar file which is there in war file

Tags: java

After adding .class file into existing war/jar file, the original war/jar file is going to currepted

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/vsoft-cts-dem-model-1.2.0.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/vsoft-cts-dem-model-1.2.0.jar'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:254)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:239)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/vsoft-cts-dem-model-1.2.0.jar'. It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:282)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:262)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:250)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Yes. What is your question?

Comment: Also, it's right there in the error message: don't compress the JAR when you modify it.

Comment: i just want to add one .class into existing jar file  which is there in war file library

Comment: Then go ahead. Just remember not to compress the JAR when you add to it (I don't know what program you're using to modify the JAR, so I can't suggest how to avoid that).

Comment: i am not using any code to modify the war/jar ,instead of coding directly i am opening archive file and adding the .class file  into archive

Comment: Yes, but with what program? WinZIP? 7-Zip? WinRAR? Default windows archive manager?

Comment: i have a spring boot application jar file, in that jar file there are so many jars are there in the lib folder,  i just  wanted to add some .class files which is there in lib folder jar file